# A question about density character of Banach spaces.

Tags: banach-spaces, tag-removed

Let $\langle M_i:i<\theta\rangle$ be an increasing chain of Banach spaces, where each $M_i$ has density character $\mu$ (i.e.,the mininum cardinality of a dense subset of $M_i$ is $\mu$). Let $B_i\subset M_i$ be a dense subset of $M_i$ of cardinality $B_i$. Notice that $\bigcup_{i<\theta}B_i$ is a dense subset of $\overline{\bigcup_{i<\theta}M_i}=:M$, so $density-character(M)\le \mu$. Is it possible to prove that $density-character(M)=\mu$? Thank you.

Comment: I think you probably mean "Let $B_i\subset M_i$ be a dense subset of $M_i$ of cardinality $\mu$" and "... so $density-character(M)\geq \mu$"; if this is what you meant, then the answer is very easily seen to be *no*. For this, take an increasing chain of separable closed subspaces in $\ell_2(\omega_1)$ whose union is all of $\ell_2(\omega_1)$ (you don't even need to take the closure).

Comment: @Philip: Perhaps it would hold if $\theta<\mu$?

Comment: @Ilya: Indeed, the answer is *yes* under the additional assumption that $\vert \theta \vert \leq \mu$).

Comment: Well, actually I mean that since $M_i$ has density character $\mu$, let $B_i\subset M_i$ be a dense subset of $M_i$ with such minimal cardinality $\mu$, it is straightforward to see that $\bigcup_{i<\theta}B_i$ is a dense subset of $M$ of size $\mu$ -since $|\theta|\le \mu$- and then $dc(M):=\min \{\lambda:$ there exists a dense subset $A$ of $M$ of size $\lambda\}\le \mu$. Even it holds if $|\theta|\le \omega$ in that example?

Comment: I see that even $dc(M)$ could decrease under these assumptions. My question is, if $dc(M)=\mu$ in general.

Comment: So, if we add the condition $|\theta|\leq \mu$ then the claim is true. Actually, you may take a dense set $B$ in $M$ and project it to $M_i$ almost orthogonally to obtain a dense set in $M_i$ of the same cardinality.

Comment: What does an almost orthogonal projection in a Banach space mean? Thank you.

Comment: Well, in this case for $b\in B$ you can simply take a point $b'\in M_i$ such that $\|b-b'\|<2\rho(b,M_i)$. Now, for every $m\in M_i$ there exists $b\in B$ such that $\|m-b\|<\varepsilon$; then $\|m-b'\|<3\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X$ is any metric space and $Y$ is any subspace of $X$ then $dc(Y) \leq dc(X)$.

Comment: Take $X:=\mathbb{R}$ and $Y:=\mathbb{I}$ with the usual metric. Notice that $dc(X)=\aleph_0$ and $dc(Y)=2^{\aleph_0}$. Does your claim hold if both $X$ and $Y$ are complete in the metric sense?

Comment: Peter $dc(\mathbb{I})=\aleph_0$ since it is in fact second countable. The claim says "any metric space" and "any subspace".

Comment: Where can I find a reference about it? Or better, how do you prove that fact? (I mean, $Y\le X$ implies $dc(Y)\le dc(X)$)?